# How to create regular expression for set followed by parenthesis in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression such that `set()` but not `set` followed by any letters or digits, `set` should only be followed by opening parenthesis.

E.g: `set(parameter1 ...n)` should pass. `setResult(parameter1...n)` should not pass.

What would be the regular expression for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
/set\(\)(?=\{)/
```

If you want some tolerance:

```
/set\s*\(.*\)(?=\s*\{)/
```

**Java** version:

```
//Use with Matcher.find() not String.matches
String setPattern = "set\\s*\\(.*\\)(?=\\s*\\{)";
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jH0wX4/4)

Comment: The issue is its not working in java.                                                             'String regText = "set\\s*\\(.*\\)(?=\\s*{)";
 String text2test = "set()\\{";
 System.out.println(regText.matches(text2test));'  The result is false

Comment: The java string require to double escape every backslash so the string will be: ``String regText = "set\\s*\\(.*\\)(?=\\s*{)``

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake, i pasted the code incorrectly here, I had double escaped it, but it is returning false

Comment: No problem, i noticed just now that the text2test String contains a literal backslash ``\\`` just before the opening brace ``{`` (not requiring escaping). The result is the literal string ``set()\{``. Remove the double backslash or if it's correct i will adjust the regex accordingly.

Comment: Yes I tried it but i get an exception of invalid sequence.

Comment: @user225008: seems like the String.matches java function has some problems with the lookahead (using compiled Pattern instead the regex is working as expected), try the updated version. Also [online](http://goo.gl/8df8gg)

Comment: I got it to work, your regular expression was correct, but using matches() method was not feasible in my case, instead I used  Matcher find() method. I don't understand why String matches() method did not work. However, I would love to understand the reason for it.

Comment: @user225008: reading the matches method documentation i discovered it, the function will match the **entire** string. So it's like to add ``^`` at the beginning and ``$`` at the end of the regex. A regex that matches a substring (just like our with a lookahead at the end) will never match!